# Sublist from List Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image: Visualforce page]I have a custom object 'product availability' which looks up to the product object. The "product availbility" object is a kind of inventory management entry.

My use case is to create a VF page which sho the amount of products available based on a region. I have created a controller which is pulling back all products , how do I divide this up into regions to show up in vf  page in the appropriate section.

Code below: Controller

```
public class ProductInventory2Controller {

public list<Product2> acc {get;set;}
public list<Product2> USA {get;set;}
public list<Product2> ASIA {get;set;}


public ProductInventory2Controller(){
    acc = [select Id,name,(select 
 Id,Allocated__c,Available__c,Calibration__c,Damaged__c,On_Rent__c,
Outbound__c,Prepared__c,Product__c,Region__c,Repair__c,Warehouses__c
from Product_Availability__r where  Region__c = 
  'Europe' ) from product2 ];
           
}
    
    
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ProductInventory2Controller">
<apex:repeat value="{!acc}" var="P">

<apex:pageblock title="{!P.Name}">
    
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!P.Product_Availability__r}" var="I">
    <apex:facet name="header">Europe</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Warehouses__c}" />    
        <apex:column value="{!I.Allocated__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Available__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Calibration__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Damaged__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Outbound__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.On_Rent__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Prepared__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Repair__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>                
    
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!P.Product_Availability__r}" var="I">
    <apex:facet name="header">USA</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Warehouses__c}" /> 
        <apex:column value="{!I.Allocated__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Available__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Calibration__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Damaged__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Outbound__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.On_Rent__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Prepared__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Repair__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!P.Product_Availability__r}" var="I">
    <apex:facet name="header">ASIA</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Warehouses__c}" /> 
        <apex:column value="{!I.Allocated__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Available__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Calibration__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Damaged__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Outbound__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.On_Rent__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Prepared__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Repair__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on Visualforce itself with the `rendered` attribute. But be careful of the record count if you are pulling all the products. Below is a sample(not tested) code for one table. Check for the other regions accordingly in other tables.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!P.Product_Availability__r}" var="I">
    <apex:facet name="header">Europe</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Warehouses__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>    
        <apex:column value="{!I.Allocated__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Available__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Calibration__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Damaged__c}"rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}" />
        <apex:column value="{!I.Outbound__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!I.On_Rent__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Prepared__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!I.Repair__c}" rendered="{!IF(I.Region__c = 'Europe', true, false)}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Check for other regions in other `pageBlockTable`s